# need help implementing nested list with name, height, and weigth for every index

Tags: python, list, nested

I want to implement a nested list that contains name (height, weight). But I can't get it to work... 
it would be something like

```
names = [john [180, 160], jimmy [190, 200], N...]
```

but that doesn't work... I've also tried

```
names = [john=(180, 160), jimmy=(190, 200), N...]
```

doesn't work either...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is a `dictionary`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

```
names = {}
names["john"] = [180, 160]
names["jimmy"] = [190, 200]

>>> names.get("john")
[180, 160]
>>> names.get("jimmy")
[190, 200]
```

Alternately, you can create an object that has `height` and `weight` attributes, and assign those in the dictionary instead of just a list.

```
class Person():
  def __init__(self, height, weight):
    self.height = height
    self.weight = weight

names = {}
names["john"] = Person(180, 160)
names["jimmy"] = Person(190, 200)

>>> names.get("john").height
180
>>> names.get("jimmy").weight
200
```

Answer (score 0):

What you would want is a key:value pair
You can do this instead `names = {'john':[180,160], 'jimmy':[190,200]}`